# Write directly to cout using boost's boost::asio::read

Tags: c++, boost-asio

So just for fun I wondered if it is possible to directly write into cout's buffer.

Given the example:

`boost::asio::read(socket,boost::asio::buffer(<buffer of cout>);`
 Data from "socket" is being read into a buffer stream, it needs to be cout's buffer.

Is is possible to write to cout without temporal stream objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly, as in zero-copy? Only if the OS supports it.

On some POSIX compliant OS-es you might be able to use the `sendfile` syscall to *actually* zero-copy the stream iff the output is being redirected to an actual file.

To be fair, it wouldn't be using `boost::asio::read` (unless hacking an overload to call `::sendfile` counts).

What you probably want is to copy the stream with minimal effort and minimal temporary memory overhead (so that, e.g. receiving a 3GB stream doesn't require more than, say, 1k of memory).

I'd suggest `boost::asio::ip::tcp::istream` with `boost::iostreams::copy`.

### Simplest

Here's a version without `boost::iostreams::copy`:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main() {
    tcp::iostream socket(tcp::endpoint {{}, 6767});
    std::cout << socket.rdbuf() << std::flush;
}
```

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d5e7fb64611f65e)</kbd>** where it prints it own source read from `netcat`.

### Using `socket`

If you *must* use an existing `tcp::socket` instance, you could:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service svc;
    tcp::socket s(svc);
    s.connect(tcp::endpoint {{}, 6767});

    tcp::iostream stream;
    stream.rdbuf()->assign(tcp::v4(), s.native_handle());

    std::cout << stream.rdbuf() << std::flush;
}
```

## Using `copy`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/acba976e69db7cd5)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main() {
    tcp::iostream socket(tcp::endpoint {{}, 6767});
    boost::iostreams::copy(socket, std::cout);
}
```

Comment: Added three samples that all achieve efficient copy without any loops/manual buffering.

Answer (score 0):

The class of ASIO `streambuf` is derived (Subtype) from the stdlib `streambuf`. Thus the following piece of code must do what you want to do:

```c++
const int to_read_bytes = 512;
boost::asio::streambuf my_buffer;
std::cout.rdbuf(&my_buffer);

// It will print into cout's buffer the read bytes
size_t n = boost::asio::read(socket, my_buffer.prepare(to_read_bytes));

// This is important as it moves the output characters to the input sequence
my_buffer.commit(n);
```

#### Links

- [ASIO streambuf](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/streambuf.html)

Comment: Yes, it "prints" (ugh) into `cout`'s buffer. But `cout` is no longer attached to standard output. Not what OP wants (by the same token you could have just named a local variable `cout`)